# How to break dates into quarters or specific period of time in r

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I'm trying to subset my data by a three-month increment.

This is the line I ran to get February, March, and April data.

`Q3 <- filtered_data %>% filter(Admin_Day >= "2022-02-01" & Admin_Day <= "2022-4-30")`

But when I checked using: `length(unique(Q3$Admin_Day))`, it gives me 332, which is obviously incorrect. There's something wrong with the filter. It included more dates than I wanted.

[image]

A side note, I was encountering the same problem when running
`Q2 <- filtered_data %>% filter(Admin_Day >= "2021-1-01" & Admin_Day <= "2022-1-31")`

but then managed to fix it by breaking the date down like the following.
`Q2 <- filtered_data %>% filter(Admin_Day >= "2021-11-01" & Admin_Day <= "2021-12-31" | Admin_Day >= "2022-01-01" & Admin_Day <= "2022-01-31")`

Thank you everyone in advance!

Comment: Convert this column to dates. While it's text, you are filtering between month "02" and "4" which could include months written "1", "2" ... "10", "11", "12" , "02", ... "09" etc.

Comment: `filtered_data$Admin_Day = lubridate::ymd(filtered_data$Admin_Day)` is a good flexible way to convert dates that might have inconsistent formatting (e.g. is Jan represented as "01" or "1" or both?), as long as it's in year - month - day order.

Comment: Once they're in date format, you can also use `lubridate::quarter(Admin_Day)` or `lubridate::floor_date(Admin_Day, "quarter")` to get either the number of the quarter or the date at the start of the quarter, which'll make filtering much simpler.

Comment: Thank you so much Jon, it's working now. I wasn't aware of such subtle formatting between 01 and 1!